# sql returned column values into comma delimited string

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

how do i get returned columns into a comma delimited string? I'm trying to get @sql to be used but had to manually type in the values.

```
declare @orderId as int, @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX)
set @orderId = 10
set @sql = 'select orderId, categoryId, itemId from Orders where orderId = ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @orderId)
--select @sql as 'sql stmt' --select orderId, categoryId, itemId from Orders where orderId = 10
--execute(@sql) 
--will return as:
--orderId categoryId itemId
--10 281 1054
declare @dt table(orderId varchar(10), categoryId varchar(10), itemId varchar(10))
--insert @dt values (@sql)
insert @dt values ('10','281','1054') -- did this to get results but want to use @sql
--how to get the @sql to be a string as '10','281','1054'
select '{"orderinfo" : [' + STUFF((
    select 
        ',{"Order Id":' + orderId
        + ',"Category Id":' + categoryId
        + ',"Item Id":' + itemId
        +'}'

    from @dt
    for xml path(''), type
 ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') + ']}' as jsonData
--end results: {"orderinfo" : [{"Order Id":10,"Category Id":281,"Item Id":1054}]}
```

I'm mostly interested in returning json formatted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @orderId as int, @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX)
set @orderId = 10
set @sql = 'select orderId, categoryId, itemId from Orders where orderId = ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @orderId)

declare @dt table(orderId varchar(10), categoryId varchar(10), itemId varchar(10))


 insert into @dt  exec(@sql)
-- this is what you needed


select '{"orderinfo" : [' + STUFF((
    select 
        ',{"Order Id":' + orderId
        + ',"Category Id":' + categoryId
        + ',"Item Id":' + itemId
        +'}'

    from @dt
    for xml path(''), type
 ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') + ']}' as jsonData
--end results: {"orderinfo" : [{"Order Id":10,"Category Id":281,"Item Id":1054}]}
```

Comment: thank you so much - i can't believe i didn't think of insert into... the executed variable -- duh

Comment: Happens all the time! Developer's block :)

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. Please also consider up-voting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a scalar-function that uses a cursor that fetches and builds a delineated string.

Then call your function on the select of your query.